# groupby + apply + lambda fail to call my function

Tags: python, function, lambda, apply

I wrote a function that should normalise values belonging to same week (dividing by the value of the first day):

```
def normalize(week):
        norm_week = (week / week[0]) -1
        return norm_week
```

I get the week data from a groupby call and I pass it to the normalise function through
the apply method (with lambda):

```
dataset['col_1_norm'] = 
dataset.groupby('week_number')['col_1'].apply(lambda x: normalize(x))
```

This is input dataset:

```
week_number   col_1 
week_1.       300 
week_1        500
.....         ... 
week_2        350
.....         ...
```

I expect the normalised values in the column "col_1_norm", but python returns multiple errors. (example -> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key))

Where am I wrong ?? Could you pls help ?
Thanks
Charlie

Comment: can you share some rows from your dataframe as `dataset.head(15).to_dict()`

Comment: here it is : {'date;week_number;Col_1': {0: '2015-03-24;2015-13;171433.8',
  1: '2015-03-25;2015-13;171437.9',
  2: '2015-03-26;2015-13;171442.0',
  3: '2015-03-27;2015-13;171446.0',
  4: '2015-03-28;2015-13;171450.1',
  5: '2015-03-29;2015-13;171454.2',
  6: '2015-03-30;2015-14;171458.2',
  7: '2015-03-31;2015-14;171462.3',
  8: '2015-04-01;2015-14;171466.4',
  9: '2015-04-02;2015-14;171470.5',
  10: '2015-04-03;2015-14;171474.5',
  11: '2015-04-04;2015-14;171478.6',
  12: '2015-04-05;2015-14;171482.7',
  13: '2015-04-06;2015-15;171486.8',
  14: '2015-04-07;2015-15;171490.8'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted a print statement in your `normalize` routine to debug:

```
def normalize(week):                                                            
    print(week)                                                                 
    norm_week = (week/week[0]) -1                                          
    return norm_week
```

Here's what printed out:

```
0      300                                                                                               
1      500                                                                                               
2      900                                                                                               
3     1300                                                                                               
4      200                                                                                               
5      400                                                                                               
6      100                                                                                               
7      800                                                                                               
8      500                                                                                               
9      600                                                                                               
10     500                                                                                               
Name: week_1, dtype: int64                                                                               
11     800                                                                                               
12    1700                
13    1800                                                                                               
14    2000                                                                                               
15    1500                                          
Name: week_2, dtype: int64                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

There's no index 0 in the week_2 group. Perhaps you meant to use `iloc`?

```
def normalize(week):                                                            
    norm_week = (week/week.iloc[0]) -1                                          
    return norm_week
```

Comment: It worked ! thanks a lot  (better if I deepen my pandas knowledge... I come from Fortan 77 :-) )